# How to configure liquibase maven plugin to generate sql output for oracle

Tags: java, mysql, oracle, maven, liquibase

I have an spring/hibernate/mysql app, and I use liquibase maven plugin (Intellij Idea) to generate DB. Here is my liquibase.properties configuration:

```
url                 jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbName
username            username
password            pass
changeLogFile       src/main/scripts/changeLog.xml
referenceUrl        hibernate:hibernate.cfg.xml
diffChangeLogFile   src/main/scripts/diffChangeLog.xml
driver              com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

As you can see, this works directly with the db, and change it on liquibase-update.

Question:
Is there any option to change my configuration to generate sql output for oracle DB? So, not to work directly with database, but to create output script.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Liquibase uses two separate actions for updating directly and generating SQL.

use `mvn liquibase:update` to update the database

use `mvn liquibase:updateSQL` to generate SQL

If the goal is bound to a lifecycle, you need to change that.

Comment: Niels, do you know if this generated sql is db (my liquibase.properties are configured for mySql) specific? May I use it for oracle?

Comment: The SQL generated is database-specific.

Comment: SteveDonie, can you show me how to configure it to be oracle 11g specific?